# Trying to understand the main function with GCC and Windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, export, program-entry-point

They say that *main()* is a function like any other function, but "marked" as an entry point inside the binary, an entry point that the operating system may find (**Don't know how**) and start the program from there. So, I'm trying to find out more about this function. What have I done? I created a simple .C file with this code inside:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     return (0);
}
```

I saved the file, installed the GCC compiler (in Windows, MingW environment) and created a batch file like this:

```
gcc -c test.c -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -nostdinc -o test.o
gcc -o test.exe -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -nostdinc -s -O2 test.o
@%comspec%
```

I did this to obtain a very simplistic compiler and linker, no library, no header, just the compiler. So, the compiling goes well but the linking stops with this error:

```
test.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to '___main'
collect2.exe: error: Id returned 1 exit status
```

I thought that the main function is exported by the linker but I believed that you didn't need any library with additional information about it. But it looks like it does. In my case I supposed that it must be the standard GCC library, so I downloaded the source code of it and opened this file: *libgcc2.c*
Now, I don't know if that is the file where the main function is constructed to be linked by GCC. In fact, I don't understand how the main function is used by GCC. Why does the linker need the gcc standard libraries? **To know what about main?** I hope this has made my question quite specific and clear. Thanks!

Comment: Can you run `nm test.o` from your windows ? It will tell you the symbols contained inside `test.o`

Comment: Yes, there's a '___main' and '_main' symbol (which is weird)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When gcc puts together all object files (test.o) and libraries to form a binary it also prepends a small object (usually crt0.o or crt1.o), which is responsible for calling your `main()`. You can see what gcc is doing, when you add `-v` on the command line:

> $ gcc -v -o test.exe test.o

crt0/crt1 does some setup and then calls into main. But the linker is finally responsible for building the executable according to the OS. With `-v` you can see also an option for the target system. In my case it's for Linux 64 bit: `-m elf_x86_64`. For your system this will be something like `-m windows` or `-m mingw`.

Comment: O.K. so the crt0.o contains platform-dependent information that is appended to the executable, so that Windows or any other O.S. can find the entry point as specified by its own rules, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because you use these two options: `-nodefaultlibs -nostdlib`

These tell GCC that it should not link your code against `libc.a`/`c.lib` which contains the code which really calls `main()`. In a nutshell, every OS is slightly different and most of them don't care about C and `main()`. Each has their own special way to start a process and most of them are not compatible with the C API.

So the solution of the C developers was to put "glue code" into the C standard library `libc.a` which contains the interface which the OS expects, creates the standard C environment (setting up the memory allocation structures so `malloc()` will map the OS's memory management functions, set up stdio, etc) and eventually calls `main()`

For C developers, this means they get a `libc.a` for their OS (along with the compiler binaries) and they don't need to care about how the setup works.

Another source of confusion is the name of the reference. On most systems, the symbolic name of `main()` is `_main` (i.e. one underscore) while `__main` is the name of an internal function called by the setup code which eventually calls the real `main()`